# Traverse foreign key and pull remote model data into Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is is possible in the admin to pull a field from a remote model, if you have a local foreign key pointing to that model?

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    [...]
    value12 = models.CharField()

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    [...]
    firstmodel = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
```

And in the Admin I want to pull in value12, any time someone views/edits SecondModel.  I figure I can do this through Inlines, but then I lose Fields and FieldSets ordering.  Any other options?  Ideal results would be sortable with fields/fieldsets, -and- read-only.

Comment: Bah, seems I can't do this with inlines, since I don't/can't have a ForeignKey on FirstModel pointing to SecondModel

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access any field in the first model as: firstmodel__value12

For the **list** view for the SecondModel:

```
list_display = ('firstmodel__value12',)
```

For the **edit** view you can use [formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides). To make it non-editable you specify a read-only widget, e.g. like [this one](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2008/12/building-read-only-field-in-django.html) or provide your own.

Comment: formfield_overrides would let me set a field read-only, but I don't see how it'll let me specify a field on a foreign model.

Comment: Passing 'firstmodel__value12' to fieldsets certainly doesn't work.

Comment: Also, ModelAdmin.readonly_fields is easier than overriding with a read-only widget.